# Group by a single character otherwise split

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following string:

`"TTTHTHTTHTTTTHTTTHTTTTTTHTTTTTHTH"`

I would like to be able to group by the T's into a list and then count the number of T's to the first H.

i.e. so like

`[3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1]`

Whats the most efficient way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is your friend

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "TTTHTHTTHTTTTHTTTHTTTTTTHTTTTTHTH"

res = [sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(s) if k == 'T']
print(res)

# [3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Alternatively, `[sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(s) if k == 'T']`. This avoids creating the `g` lists, so it's a bit more efficient, and it avoids using RAM for those temporary lists. That's irrelevant here, but it's handy when the groups are expected to be large.

Comment: That is true, I keep forgetting about the handy `sum(1 for _ in x)`. I'll edit that in. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. But don't totally delete the `len(list(g))`: It's good for people to know about both options.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in one line with a list comprehension:

```
my_string = "TTTHTHTTHTTTTHTTTHTTTTTTHTTTTTHTH"
my_list = [len(i) for i in my_string.split('H') if len(i)>0]
```

Output of `my_list`:

```
[3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I had originally tried it this way, but it includes 0's in the output which isn't what i want.

Comment: I edited to reflect that, still works better (and more readable, and less code) than other answers

Comment: Yeah thanks - I think I missed the itertools however - which might help with some of the other stuff i'm doing :)

Comment: Your question, your choice... happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with itertools:

```
import itertools
s = "TTTHTHTTHTTTTHTTTHTTTTTTHTTTTTHTH"
counts = []
count = 1
for a, b in zip(s, s[1:]):
    if a==b:
        count += 1
    elif a == "T":
        counts.append(count)
        count = 1
```

gives:

```
   counts
=> [3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using list comprehension :

```
my_string = "TTTHTHTTHTTTTHTTTHTTTTTTHTTTTTHTH"

strips = my_string.strip('H')
splits = strips.split('H' )

# generating iterables of 1 and then summation 
my_list = [sum(1 for i in j) for j in splits]

print(my_list )
```

gives

```
[3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1]

[Program finished]
```